# CSS Previous element

Tags: html, css

Is there a way to achieve this with **CSS**?
**element height = 100% minus previous element height**

Please don't provide JavaScript answers, because I already have:

CSS:

```
.mydiv{
    height:100%;
}
```

JavaScript (jQuery):

```
$('.mydiv').each(function(){
    $(this).css('height', $(this).height() - $(this).prev().height());
});
```

Actually, I want to reproduce the second effect of [this demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Wct6W/) using only CSS.
Thanks

**Edit:**
What I exactly want to achieve: I want two elements to fit vertically in their parent, **without specifying the first element height**

Comment: Pretty sure you need to JS to do this, sorry. I haven't seen any ways to do calculations in CSS.

Comment: While there is the ability to use `expression` in CSS, it is only supported by IE.  In addition, there is no way to reference the previous element in CSS alone.  You may consider looking into an alternative stylesheet language, such as [LESS](http://lesscss.org/).

Comment: Well actually... LESS and SASS are awesome, but they are CSS compilers, not an alternative stylesheet language. Actually, I don't even think CSS qualifies as a language. Carry on...

Comment: Does the second div need to be 100% in height or can it just "look like if it has 100% height". Cause you could fake that with background color. But only if the height of second div does not matter - if it has to be 100% than you cannot do this without JS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `display:table` and `display:table-row` to achieve this with CSS

[There is the demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Wct6W/2/)

Comment: Almoust perfect! Worked fine on FF, Chrome, Opera, Safari, IE9, IE8, is just that this doesn't work on IE7, any suggestion?

Comment: I use `*+overflow:hidden` to fix it on IE7 demo:http://jsfiddle.net/a3Bmx/ ,I would also like to know the other better idea

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve the layout without doing math using both `top` and `bottom`

http://jsfiddle.net/UNnGP/

Comment: What if content of top div exceeds 50px?

Comment: And what if content of top div is less than 50px? I **do not want to specify the height**

Comment: The table solution will work, but it will introduce other side effects like changing the way padding, margin, and vertical-align work. If you really can't specify the height of either one, I would fake it by [putting the same background from the second box on the parent](http://jsfiddle.net/XKUdy/1/)

Answer (score 0):

No, for 2 reasons:

1. CSS doesn't have a concept of "previous". There are a few selectors that will use elements after (e.g. "+", "~"), but not before.
2. I was thinking there might be some clever way taking advantage of CSS's inheriting powers, but I don't think that would work either. You may be able to set a height to 50% of its parent's, but you would be overriding its original height, therefore ruining the chances of performing a `this.height - prev.height` type of thing.

Simple answer is no.

Comment: Actually what you should ask here is if it has to look like that or behave like that. Cause if it only has to look like that it could be done.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can. But you have to have overflow:hidden on your container.
Here is a link. http://jsfiddle.net/UNnGP/4/

Comment: This doesn't help, because it will hide **content** that I want to display

Comment: Well, your jquery version does it to. Or it flows over. Doesn't look nice